# Using cleditor in Internet Explorer 9 causes double-quotes to be incorrectly escaped

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, cleditor

I've scoured the internet looking for an answer to this problem but, alas, I am forced to ask for help.

I am using the [cleditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/) jQuery plugin for its Rich Text/HTML editing capabilities.  For the most part, it works fine.  However, there's a weird problem if I do the following in IE9:

1. Click the "Show Source" button at the top right of the toolbar to switch to HTML Mode
2. Paste the following snippet:

   ```
   <p>Note the double-quotes</p>
   <div onclick='alert("hi")'>click me</div>
   ```
3. Switch back to Rich Text Mode and make a trivial change (for e.g., add a space)
4. Switch again to HTML Mode

Note how the double-quotes are now incorrectly escaped like this:

```
<div onclick="alert(\"hi\")">click me</div>
```

What the heck is going on here?  Other browsers escape the double-quotes properly like this:

```
<div onclick="alert(&quot;hi&quot;)">click me</div>
```

I've tried to using the entity, `&quot;`, myself but it doesn't matter - IE9 still messes it up.  Does anyone know how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out.  If anyone else is struggling with this issue, I think it's the combination of using cleditor, the XHTML plugin and Internet Explorer.

You can fix it by adding this JavaScript Snippet before your cleditor code:

```
(function ($) {
    var oldCallback = $.cleditor.defaultOptions.updateTextArea;

    $.cleditor.defaultOptions.updateTextArea = function (html) {
        if (oldCallback) {
            html = oldCallback(html);
        }

        var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;
        if (isIE) {
            return html.replace(/\\\"/g, "&quot;");
        } else {
            return html;
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Alternatively, you can do the conditional replacement in jquery.cleditor.js (line 1126 for cleditor v1.3.0).